# A Sobolev embedding theorem for functions on spheres

Tags: fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis, sobolev-spaces, fourier-transform, harmonic-functions

$L^2(\mathbb{S}^{d-1})$ is embedded in $H^{-s}(\mathbb{R}^d)$ with $s>\frac{1}{2}$, which means for $f\in L^2(\mathbb{S}^{d-1})$, the following holds:
$$\DeclareMathOperator{\Dm}{\operatorname{d}\!}
\int\limits_{\mathbb{R}^d} \bigg|\int\limits_{\mathbb{S}^{d-1}}f(\omega)e^{-2\pi i x\cdot \omega}\Dm\sigma(\omega)\bigg|^2\frac{\Dm x}{(1+|x|^2)^s}\lesssim \int_{\mathbb{S}^{d-1}}|f(\omega)|^2 \Dm\sigma(\omega)
$$

This is a lemma in Luis Vega's article [1] (Page 2). He gives a somewhat roundabout proof. Intuitively, it may help to expand $f$ into spherical harmonics. But I don't know the accurate behavior of spherical harmonics under Fourier transform.

Could you please present a proof or give a explicit expression of spherical harmonics' Fourier transform?

Another idea from Willie Wong is to use Fourier restriction. By Tomas-Stein, we can deduce the conclusion when $s>\frac{d}{d+1}$.

**Reference**

[1] Luis Vega, "Schrödinger equations: Pointwise convergence to the initial data" (English) Proceeding of the American Mathematical Society 102, No. 4, 874-878 (1988), [DOI 10.2307/2047326](https://doi.org/10.2307/2047326), [MR0934859](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=MR0934859), [Zbl 0654.42014](https://zbmath.org/?q=an%3A0654.42014).

Comment: Maybe the wiki on [plane wave expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane-wave_expansion) is helpful here? + some asymptotics of Bessel functions

Comment: IIRC how spherical harmonics transform under Fourier transform is discussed in Stein & Weiss, _Introduction for Fourier Analysis on Euclidean Spaces_ (Chapter 4). But the sort of decay results that guarantees embedding into $H^{-s}$ are more related to Fourier restriction theorems, and I don't think the spherical harmonics expansion help that much.

Comment: For the questioner: do you extend functions from the sphere to the ambient Euclidean spaces by degree-zero homogeneity? Or just to consider them as distributions supported on the sphere? Could you clarify?

Comment: Those $f$ may be considered as distributions supported on the sphere, as the inequality says.

Comment: When $f=1$, this works because of the decay of $\widehat{\sigma}$, which is perhaps restating what Willie already said above. (Or it's completely unhelpful since this doesn't give one any idea what one would do with a very irregular $f$.)

Answer (score 2):

As noted in Vega's article, this statement is a special case of the trace theorem, which in particular says that the restriction operator, which restricts a test function to a compact submanifold $\Omega$ of codimension $1$, is bounded from $H^s(\mathbb{R}^d)$ to $L^2(\Omega)$ for $s>1$. The lemma is than a statement about boundedness of the adjoint operator. However, I don't know where to find a proof of the trace theorem in a sufficiently convenient form (with restriction to a submanifold, but with Sobolev spaces described in terms of the Fourier transform), which is probably also why Vega found it easier to give a full proof.

I should also note that the main result from Vega's paper has been superseded by https://annals.math.princeton.edu/2019/189-3/p04

Answer (score 0):

This inequality may be proved by a calm calculation. We can assume that $f$ supports near $(0,\cdots,0,1)\in \mathbb{S}^{d-1}$. Denote the first $d-1$ coordinates of $x\in \mathbb{R}^d$ by $x^{'}$. We have
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
(fd\sigma)^{\vee}(x^{'},t)&=\int_{\mathbb{S}^{d-1}}f(\omega)e^{2\pi i(x^{'},t)\cdot\omega} d\sigma(\omega) \\
&=\int_{\{y^{'}\in \mathbb{R}^{d-1}:|y^{'}|^2\leq 1-c^2\}} f(y^{'},\sqrt{1-|y^{'}|^2})e^{2\pi ix^{'}\cdot y^{'}}e^{2\pi it\sqrt{1-|y^{'}|^2}} \frac{dy^{'}}{\sqrt{1-|y^{'}|^2}} \\
&=\mathscr{F}^{-1} (f(y^{'},\sqrt{1-|y^{'}|^2})\frac{e^{2\pi it\sqrt{1-|y^{'}|^2}}}{\sqrt{1-|y^{'}|^2}})(x^{'})
\end{split}
\end{equation*}
where $^{\vee}$ is the inverse Fourier transform in $\mathbb{R}^d$ and $\mathscr{F}^{-1}$ in $\mathbb{R}^{d-1}$.
Then by Plancherel,
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\int_{\mathbb{R}^d} |\int_{\mathbb{S}^{d-1}}f(\omega)e^{2\pi i x\cdot \omega}d\sigma(\omega)|^2\frac{d x}{(1+|x|^2)^s}&\leq \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} |\int_{\mathbb{S}^{d-1}}f(\omega)e^{2\pi i (x^{'},t)\cdot \omega}d\sigma(\omega)|^2 dx^{'}\frac{d t}{(1+|t|^2)^s} \\
&=\int_{\mathbb{R}}\int_{\mathbb{R^{d-1}}}|f(y^{'},\sqrt{1-|y^{'}|^2})\frac{e^{2\pi it\sqrt{1-|y^{'}|^2}}}{\sqrt{1-|y^{'}|^2}}|^2 dy^{'}\frac{d t}{(1+|t|^2)^s} \\
&=C_s\int_{\mathbb{S}^{d-1}}|f(\omega)|^2 d\sigma(\omega)
\end{split}
\end{equation}